# Simple Web-crawler (routine)

Tags: web-crawler

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to create a database based on public information displayed daily by a public website (a small table of 50 rows and 5 columns).
My ideia is to enter this website 4 times per day and store a table that is displayed in this website. I need some help/hints with the following points which I believe I should attack in order to build this database:

1) Which programming language should I use?

2) Where should I store the program?

3) Where it would store the data?

4) How should the program work? [two questions here: i) how to enter the website and store the data; ii) how to do it everyday, 4 times a day at specific times]

Any hints on any of these issues would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I would code this in JavaScript, more specifically a Google Apps Script.
- The program (Script) will be stored in your Google Drive
- You could store the data in a Google Spreadsheet or the Google ScriptDB
- You create a timed trigger that runs your 'update' function 4 times a day.
- - Use UrlFetchApp (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to retrieve the web page content, parse the content, and then store the parsed data in ScriptDB (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/script-db/)
- - Time-driven triggers (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_time_triggers)

You can publish your script as a web app and allow people to view your results if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked really well.
I'm still trying to figure out how to get a specific table of the html code, but if i'm unable to do it with GAS I'll just when i'm dealing with the database.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

You've got to be really beginning programmer if you ask ME what language should you use. I would answer with a question for that: and what language do you know?

The easiest way in my opinion would be small php script that would store information either in file or database run 4 times a day as cron job.

Comment: thanks for the sarcasm... the point is that I need to build the database and actually just program in VBA and statistical softwares...  (and I actually didn't ask YOU)

Comment: yes, you did ask me... if you ask here, you ask me and millions of users in here.